# FullCalendar and MySQL -- Optimize my Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a follow-up question regarding an issue I previously had on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029989/fullcalendar-and-mysql-event-spanning-multiple-months).  I would like to know how to further optimize/refine my issue.

My **old** query was:

```
-- OLD QUERY --
SELECT start, end, title, details, location
FROM event
WHERE (start >= 2012-02-26 00:00:00 AND end <= 2012-04-01 00:00:00)
AND user_id= $user_id;
```

This query works great because it does not get old events, say from January. So the query is fast and efficient.  **But,** it does not work for queries that may overlap into the next month.  (Let's say an event has a "start_date" of 2012-03-29, but an "end_date" of 2012-04-05.  Well, then it's not pulled in the query, thus, not displaying.

So, my **new** query ended up being:

```
-- NEW QUERY --
SELECT start, end, title, details, location
FROM event
WHERE (end > 2012-02-26 00:00:00 OR start < 2012-04-01 00:00:00)
AND user_id= $user_id;
```

But, with the new query, it ends up pulling ALL events prior to 02-26-2012, thus making it VERY slow and inefficent.

**How can I optimize this query to achieve both of these:**

a) Make it work so that it gathers events that span the end of one month into another?
b) And at the same time NOT query every single other event in the past?

Hopefully there's a way to do this!  Thanks very much for any input.

Comment: Ur question i snot clear can you pls simplify it?

Comment: Hi OM The Eternity, I tried to simplify my request above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find overlapping events, change `OR` to `AND` in your query (changed the dates slightly to get overlaps with March only):

```
WHERE (end >= '2012-03-01' AND start < '2012-04-01')
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be working.  Thanks very much for your help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an additional and in your where statement?

Something like

```
SELECT start, end, title, details, location
FROM event
WHERE (end > $start OR start < $end)
 AND user_id= $user_id AND $end >CURDATE();
```

This seems like it would only pull events that haven't ended yet.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response.  I tried this, but then it pulls  every single future event.  So if someone has 1,000 events all the way through 2015, they all show up in the response.

Comment: It shouldn't pull anything more than what your original query does. Where statements typically limit data not add more to it. What does your original query pull?